# no entiendo por que me regresa ese valor c++

Tags: c++, funciones, lógica

estoy aprendiendo a programar en c++ y llegue al tema de funciones. El problema que estoy intentando resolver es el siguiente:  Escriba una funcion escribeNumeros(int ini, int fin) que devuelva en la salida estandar los numeros del ini al fin. Escriba una version que escriba los numeros en orden ascendente.

Creo que lo hice bien ya que si los imprime en orden ascendente pero al final siempre imprime el primer numero que ingrese.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int escribeNum(int ini,int fin);

int main(){
int inicio,fins;
int x,i;

cout<<"Desde que número empezaré: ";
cin>>inicio;
cout<<"En que número quiere finalizar: ";
cin>>fins;




    cout<<escribeNum(inicio,fins);


  getch();
  return 0;
  }

 int escribeNum(int x,int y){
  int pot;

   if(y==x){
        pot = y;
       cout<<pot;
     }else{
        pot = x;
        cout<<pot;
        escribeNum(x+1,y);
    
   }
    return pot;
```

}

Honestamente no se por que sea. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Muchas gracias!

Comment: cout<<escribeNum(inicio,fins);

Comment: lo pongo en el else?

Comment: `cout<<escribeNum(inicio,fins);` te sobra el `cout`, si se lo sacas seguramente te va a imprimir como quieres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un **ciclo for** que vaya desde la **variable ini** hasta la **variable fin**:

```
void escribeNum(int x, int y)
{
    for(int i = x; i <= y; i++)
    {
        cout<<i;
    }
}
```

Fijate que yo cambié el tipo de retorno de la función de **int** a **void**, es decir ahora la función no retorna nada, debes cambiar también el tipo de retorno cuando declaras la función:

```
void escribeNum(int ini,int fin);
```

Y para usar la función harías:

```
escribeNum(inicio, fins);
```

Usando **recursividad** como tienes en tu ejemplo quedaría:

```
int escribeNum(int x, int y)
{
    cout<<x;

    if(x == y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return(escribeNum(x + 1, y));
}
```

Mientras **x** no sea igual a **y** la función seguirá llamándose recursivamente, e imprimiendo el valor de **x**, cuando **x == y** se cumple el caso base y se detienen las llamadas recursivas.

Comment: muchas gracias Japv me fue muy util!

Comment: @JorgeSI si la respuesta te fue util no olvides marcarla como aceptada, gracias